# Auditctl. Auditd. Monitor Link creation. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, ssh, tty, logging, rsyslog

Is it possible to monitor creation of link of file? For example, I create file `audit_file`, so I want to create the rule which triggers when such a command is executed `ln -s /home/user/audit_file link_to_audit_file`.